# How should I approach for creating a command-line parser in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-line, command-line-arguments

Hi I want to create my own command-line parser using java. As you might know, the design of this parser can be in a lot of ways.

I found this http://jcommander.org/ but this seems more complex than I hoped.

I have more simple questions like;

- What kind of data structures can i use to store options and
  parameters?
- When I capture the commands, how should I execute them?

Can you give me something more in the starting stage. Can be a class design approach or some little library that you know.

Comment: There is also [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) , why invent the wheel?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher i agree with him, but if you want to do it for educationnal purposes, you can use Interpreter design pattern.